# EADDRINUSE when connecting to Memcached service from node.js

Tags: php, node.js, memcached

New to Node.js. Searched lots of answers in SO, but could not find appropriate solution for this issue. I'm using custom memcache server code for node.js for getting data from memcached service (stored using php), added only relevant code below:

```
var net = require("net");
net.createServer(function(socket) {
     socket.setEncoding('utf8');

     var cmd = {};
     var incoming = '';
     socket.addListener('receive', function(data) {
         incoming += data;
         // in the mid of receiving some data, so we can't
         // parse it yet.
         if(data.substring(data.length - 2) != '\r\n')
            return;

         data = incoming;
         incoming = '';

         var parts = data.split(/ /);
         if(parts[0].match(/^(add|set|delete|get|gets)$/i)) {
             switch(parts[0]) {
                 case 'add':
                     var message = JSON.parse(data.split('\r\n')[1]);
                     self._add.call(socket, parts[1].replace('\r\n', ''), message);
                     break;

                 case 'set':
                     var message = data.split('\r\n')[1];
                     try {
                        message = JSON.parse(message);
                     } catch(e) {}
                        var subparts = parts[1].replace('\r\n', '').split('/');
                        self._set.call(socket, subparts.slice(0, 2), subparts.slice(2).join('/'), message);
                 break;

                 case 'delete':
                     self._delete.call(socket, parts[1].replace('\r\n', ''));
                 break;

                 case 'get':
                     self._get.call(socket, parts[1].replace('\r\n', ''));
                 break;

                 case 'gets':
                     var getsparts = parts.slice(1);
                     getsparts[getsparts.length - 1] =
                     getsparts[getsparts.length - 1].replace('\r\n', '');
                     self._gets.call(socket, getsparts);
                 break;
            }
         }
     });
}).listen(11211, "localhost");
```

But whenever i try to start the node server, it says `EADDRINUSE`, as this is due to the reason that memcached service is already running on port `11211`. If i change the port to something else such as (51242) then the error does not show up, but no data is retrieved from memcached.

So is there any way i can connect to memcached service using same port `11211` from this node.js memcache server code..?
I'm new to Node.js, so could not figure out any posible solution. So, how can i fix this issue **without using any node.js memcached modules**, or am i completely on the wrong path..? As a side note I'm running memcached service and nodejs on windows 7.  Please suggest

**Update**

Instead of

```
net.createServer(function(socket) {
```

I changed to following for test

```
this.start = function() {
        var socket = net.createConnection(11211, "127.0.0.1");
        console.log('Socket created.');
        socket.on('data', function(data) {          
            console.log('RESPONSE: ' + data);
        }).on('connect', function() {

            socket.write("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n");
        }).on('end', function() {
             console.log('DONE');
        });
}
```

but on console, it shows Socket Created, and then throws error:: Error connect `ECONNREFUSED`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because node should be interacting with memcached, not as a *server* (which binds the ports and accepts incoming connections), but as a *client*. Look into [net.createConnection](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_port_host_connectlistener) instead of net.createServer.

Comment: thanks for the reply, will check using createConnection instead.

Comment: Please update your code above to accurately represent what you're doing now.

Comment: restarted everything and it worked fine using net.createConnection.. thanks for the help.. :)